# Minicom shows nothing

Tags: ubuntu, embedded

```
~$dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[   15.905810] usb 3-3: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 3910.549952] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303 converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 3929.763287] usb 3-3: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0


~$lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port

Minicom configuration
| A -    Serial Device      : /dev/ttyUSB0                              |
| B - Lockfile Location     : /var/lock                                 |
| C -   Callin Program      :                                           |
| D -  Callout Program      :                                           |
| E -    Bps/Par/Bits       : 115200 8N1                                |
| F - Hardware Flow Control : No                                        |
| G - Software Flow Control : No                                        |
```

Then it gives and nothing else happens

```
Welcome to minicom 2.4

OPTIONS: I18n                                                                
Compiled on Jan 25 2010, 07:02:36.                                           
Port /dev/ttyUSB0                                                            

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
```

I googled a lot and followed various tutos. But the problem is still there. I wondering if it is some problem with the board itself?

Please help, thanks

Edit 1: Sorry for not clarify the question. In fact, I connected to a pandaboard OMAP4430.

Edit 2: Well, actually I got it work. The problem is that the uboot image is broken, so I use JTAG to reflash a new one. Sorry for not clarify the problem and make this question troublesome.

Comment: Nowhere in this question have you explained what you have connected to dev/ttyUSB0  or what you expect to appear.  Do you *know* that the connected device is outputting anything?  This is not a really programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after turning off hardware flow control in minicom you have to exit and then return for it to take effect.

you need to check your baud rate too, ctrl-a p  and then next lower or whatever.

what are you sending to the computer?  can you use a paperclip between socket 2 and 3 on the serial port to make a loop back.  The rule is women are always right, when looking at the d-shell connector with the wider part on top if sockets then the top right pin is pin one, two is to the left of that on the top row and so on.  if pins and not sockets then top left is pin one, these days the connectors generally have raised numbers in the plastic molding.  with the short in place what you type on the minicom window should loop back and be seen on the screen.

are there any other /dev/tty* devices that you have not accounted for, maybe you have two /dev/ttyUSBx devices and you are focusing on the wrong one.

Comment: I guess computer side is a male connector, if you have a null modem cable, or a gender bender then you can use the paperclip to short pins 2 and 3 to make it a loopback.